# How do I use the SQL COUNT() function properly in this context?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query that tells me how many users there are that have one or more products.

I created this query which tells me all of the users that have products:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.*
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `products`
ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
```

However, I want the count of the users, not the users themselves.

So I created this query which uses the `COUNT()` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `products`
ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
```

But I believe I'm using the `COUNT` incorrectly because this query returns `164` which is a lot more than the previous query returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `users`.`id`)
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `products`
ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` filters your result rows to be unique. The aggregation (i.e. the `COUNT()`) is done prior, so is following your `JOIN` and counting users twice.

So, to get the number of users that have products, you could do:

```
SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)

FROM        users    AS u

INNER JOIN  products AS p
    ON      u.id = p.creator_id
```

Similarly, you could do something a bit useful, like the count of products per user:

```
SELECT      u.id,
            COUNT(*) AS ProductCount

FROM        users    AS u

INNER JOIN  products AS p
    ON      u.id = p.creator_id

GROUP BY    u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query may be more efficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `users` u
WHERE exists (select 1 from `products` p where u.id = p.creator_id);
```

Performance will be best with an index on `product(creator_id)`.  And, performance will be better than the `join`/`count(distinct)` version when some users have many products.

Comment: Oh `EXISTS`  you're so efficient and underutilized.